# Replace UTF-8 characters with shell perl

Tags: perl, unicode

How do I get `perl` to properly replace UTF-8 character from a shell?

*The examples use stdin, but I need something that works for `perl ... file` too.*

This is what I expect:

```
$ echo ABCæøåDEF | perl -CS -pe "s/([æøå])/[\\1]/g"
ABC[æ][ø][å]DEF
```

This is what I get:

```
$ echo ABCæøåDEF | perl -CS -pe "s/([æøå])/[\\1]/g"
ABCæøåDEF
```

Replacing the Unicode characters with ASCII works instantly:

```
$ echo ABC123DEF | perl -CS -pe "s/([123])/[\\1]/g"
ABC[1][2][3]DEF
```

My environment:

```
perl 5.18.2
Bash 3.2.57
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Use this :

```
 $ echo 'ABCæøåDEF' |
    perl -CSD -Mutf8 -pe 's/([æøå])/[$1]/g'
```

Works also for files

### Output :

```
ABC[æ][ø][å]DEF
```

### Note :

- substitutions: `\\1` is for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), `\1` is for [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) and in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) we use `$1`
- check `perldoc perlrun` for `-CSD` utf8 tricks

Comment: Very nice! I know you can do `export PERL_UNICODE=S` to avoid `-CS`. Is there a similar thing you can do to avoid `-Mutf8`? `alias perl="/usr/bin/perl -Mutf8"` if nothing else? I always use UTF-8.

Comment: Please read this authoritative post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129

Comment: I see. `perl` is not meant for Unicode. At least not in any sane way. I need it to work for files too, not stdin. So I'll use another language.

Comment: Check my edited post for files

Comment: Instead of `perl -CS -Mopen=":std,IN,:encoding(utf-8)"`, why not `perl -CSD`?

Comment: @forthrin Re *"`perl` is not meant for Unicode."* Perl has excellent Unicode support, but for backwards compatibility it is not enabled by default, including for oneliners. If all you use Perl for is oneliners, then yes, you may have to jump through some hoops, but if you write scripts, then you'll have an easier time.

Comment: I agree @haukex, perl is really good at Unicode parsing

Comment: What I need is a string replacement tool on the command line, because this is something I do very often. I can confirm that your suggestion works for both stdin and files. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your input:

```
$ cat input.txt 
ABCæøåDEF
$ hexdump -C input.txt 
00000000  41 42 43 c3 a6 c3 b8 c3  a5 44 45 46 0a           |ABC......DEF.|
0000000d
```

One good way IMO is the [`-C` option](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-C-[_number/list_]*) plus [`utf8`](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html):

```
$ perl -CSD -Mutf8 -pe 's/([æøå])/[$1]/g' input.txt 
ABC[æ][ø][å]DEF
$ cat input.txt | perl -CSD -Mutf8 -pe 's/([æøå])/[$1]/g'
ABC[æ][ø][å]DEF
```

If you don't want to use UTF-8 on the command line, you can always write your Perl code in plain ASCII and use escapes such as `\xAB`, `\x{ABCD}`, or in newer Perls `\N{U+ABCD}` or `\N{CHARNAME}`:

```
$ perl -CSD -pe 's/([\xE6\xF8\xE5])/[$1]/g' input.txt 
ABC[æ][ø][å]DEF
$ cat input.txt | perl -CSD -pe 's/([\xE6\xF8\xE5])/[$1]/g'
ABC[æ][ø][å]DEF
```

This one is getting a little creative: `@ARGV` will be interpreted as UTF-8, so you can keep your source code as ASCII and pass the UTF-8 characters via a command line argument (not necessarily the nicest solution, just showing how you could make use of the the `-CA` option):

```
$ perl -CSDA -pe 'BEGIN{$p=shift;} s/($p)/[$1]/g' '[æøå]' input.txt 
ABC[æ][ø][å]DEF
$ cat input.txt | perl -CSDA -pe 'BEGIN{$p=shift;} s/($p)/[$1]/g' '[æøå]'
ABC[æ][ø][å]DEF
```

Or, of course you can always turn the oneliner into an actual script, where you can

```
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use utf8;
use open qw/:std :encoding(UTF-8)/;
use charnames qw/:full :short/;
```

Further reading: [perlunitut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html), [perlunifaq](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html), [perluniintro](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html), [perlunicode](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html), [perlunicook](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicook.html).

Comment: Appreciate the information about the alternative character syntaxes.

Answer (score -2):

$ echo 'ABCæøåDEF' |
    perl -CS -Mutf8 -pe 's/([æøå])/[$1]/g'